# I have 10 squads but only space for 4 to be in the office on any given day of the week. How to create the optimal rota?

Tags: combinatorics

I have 10 squads but only capacity for 4 to be in the office on any given day of the working week (Monday - Friday).

5 working days * 4 squads per day = 20 squads per week meaning 2 days in the office per squad, working from home the other 3 days.

The 10 squads can be divided into 3 distinct groups i.e. [A1, A2, A3] [B1, B2, B3] & [C1, C2, C3, C4].

It's important for each group of squads to be in the office together one day of the week and I'm happy to fix that day for consistency i.e. A1, A2 & A3 to be in the office together every Tuesday, squads B1, B2 & B3 to be in the office together every Wednesday & squads C1, C2, C3 & C4 to be in the office together every Thursday.

Monday - 4 available
Tuesday - 1 available
Wednesday - 1 available
Thursday - 0 available
Friday - 4 available

Question is, week by week, how do I go about building a rota to schedule in the 2nd office day for each of the 10 squads with the following objectives in mind:

Over a reasonable period of time (let's say in a 6 or 12 month period), each of the ten squads has a fair share of Mondays and Fridays in the office.

Outside of each squads fixed day (where they will always be in the office with the other squads in their group), over the months they would ideally spend a similar amount of time in the office with each squad from outside their group so they get to know each other.

Comment: A simple approach would be to randomly shuffle the squads into the 10 available slots each week (starting with Tuesday and Wednesday where you only have 7 squads to choose from).

Comment: Some of the details presented seem to be constraints (e.g. a squad can only be in the office twice a week, other three days working at home), while other details seem to be "objectives" (e.g. a similar amount of time in the office with squads in different groups).  The problem seems to me more of a trial-and-error programming exercise, rather than a formal mathematical problem.  Given enough time the "fair share" of Mondays and Fridays can always be made to even out.  Perhaps a good way to proceed if you want help is to produce your own rotation schedule for twelve weeks and ask to better it.